# xCode6 > testFlight "Missing 64-bit support "

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, testflight

Been all around with this one, still needing help

1) In xCode when I am archiving to submit to TestFlight I get the following error

[image]

2) I have researched and changed the architecture to Arm64 and the Debug to Yes The Build to No
The build completely Fails
[image]

3) & I get the LLVM Warning

[image]

So I change the optimization Level from Fastest to Fast

[image]

4) Normally I could build to my phone / unplug it and then Archive.
But I can't get as far as a build to my phone anymore. This is a project coming from Unity that has worked well in the past.

I work with AR some bundles that now give errors so I take them off 
I also add the Core Text Framework to get rid of the Mach-O errors

I'm running the latest Unity the latest xCode in hopes of bug fixes
I have even tried reverting to older version of Unity

Thanks

~ Be

Comment: Mention the unity version that you are using. And please attach the screenshot of unity player settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use latest version of unity and Xcode. When you build your project in unity, change architecture type to universal in player setting.

Comment: Did you tried to build with different stripping levels?